# Using df in Solr query with array of strings

Tags: solr5

I have field in my indexed data set called "sighting_en".  It contains an array of strings.

When I perform a query using &df=sighting_en I get back zero results.

When I perform a query using another field that is just defined as a plain string, it works fine.

Is there something in my syntax that I need to change or is there something in a config file that needs to be modified to allow this field to be used with 'df'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array of string, use multiValued="true" in schema.

Eg. field name="sighting_en" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"

After indexing, say the array values are {"aaa","bbb"},searching "&df=sighting_en:aaa" will give results as requested.